# Drupal distro for landing pages

Tags: 7

At my current work we do often landing pages (with their own domain)
I was wandering if someone already thought to do them with Drupal:

A multi-site (only one database) with several landing pages, each of them with their own domain. Anyone did it already?

How to face the multidomain feature?
Which are the best modules for accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have yo check the [domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain)? I think is the best option to solve this.

Another option, but more complex will be to create a Drupal as publisher backend and also Drupal as front end to the differents domains, you can share the content with feeds.

Oskar